# How to disable the call (is it possible) from custom contact screen in iphone?

Tags: ios, iphone

Currently I am working on a simple iphone app, using ABPeopleNavigationViewController to create a Custom contact screen for the user to pick the phone number to send a message. But my problem, when the user select the phone number it automatically makes a call.

So how to disable the call from custom contact screen in iphone?